# Does express-generator add a view after the scaffold is done?

Tags: express, express-generator

What I am trying to understand is: If after creation of `express -v pug -c sass projectoName`
is it possible to add views using the scafold Express-generator. For example, a partial for the footer, another for the navbar and so on...
In short: How to add a new page with the tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The express generator is a tool for the initial app creation and configuration. It creates a basic app structures, configures the view engine, the css engine... But it stops there.

Once you have made the command `express -v pug -c sass projectoName`, you are done with the express-generator. If you want a new view (complete or partial), you have to create a new file (a pug file in this case) in your views folder, manually.

It is not like the Ruby on Rails generator for example which can generate views, models, or scaffold a full CRUD.

There are other frameworks, like Sails.js (based on express.js) which have a [command line interface](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface) and a generate command.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.